# What does the checkbox "Build target platform based on the target's installed plug-ins" do?

Tags: eclipse

In Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform, there is a checkbox "Build target platform based on the target's installed plug-ins".  What is this asking?

I am using Eclipse 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit F1 to open the Help and you'll find the following:

> How PDE builds it target platform is
>   dictated by the **Build target platform
>   based on target's installed plug-ins**
>   preference. When this preference is
>   enabled, PDE will attempt to locate
>   the target location's list of
>   installed plug-ins inside a
>   configuration file (platform.xml or
>   bundles.info). If PDE finds this file,
>   it will build the target platform
>   based on the plug-ins inside the
>   configuration file. If it doesn't find
>   the file, PDE will just manually scan
>   the target location directory for the
>   list of plug-ins.

HTH Tom